# Overriding an abstract getter after a TypeScript Mixin

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-mixins

I have an app using some generic classes with the [Mixin pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), and am trying to implement a property getter that's the same for 90% of users of the mixin, but not quite all...

I was surprised to find:

1. It's fine to define abstract methods, implement them in the mixin, and override them in a child class
2. It's fine to define new property getters *in the mixin* and override them in the child class
3. **But**, trying to define abstract property getters, *implement* them in the mixin, and override them in the child class - raises an error?

and found an unexpected issue when I tried to **override a property getter** defined in the mixin on a child class.

Below is a small code snippet that tries to demonstrate all 3 behaviours - can anybody help me understand why point #3 is an error and whether there's a good way to fix it? I'd like to keep the safety of any children of `TextThing` being forced to implement the abstract property...

```js
/**
 * Basic interface objects should implement
 */
export interface ITextThing<T> {
  dataSource: T;
  html(): string;
  get text(): string;
}

/**
 * Abstract base class with partial implementation
 */
export abstract class TextThing<T> implements ITextThing<T> {
  dataSource: T;

  constructor(data: T) {
    this.dataSource = data;
  }

  abstract html(): string;
  abstract get text(): string;
}

type AbstractOrConcreteConstructor<T> = (new (...args: any[]) => T) | (abstract new (...args: any[]) => T);

/**
 * A mixin with extra functionality
 */
export function WithCounter<T extends AbstractOrConcreteConstructor<{}>>(SuperClass: T) {
  return class extends SuperClass {
    _counter: number;

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this._counter = 0;
    }

    get count(): number {
      return this._counter;
    }

    get text(): string {
      return `[${this._counter}]`;
    }
  };
}

/**
 * The problem class: Using the mixin...
 */
export class TextWithCounter<TData> extends WithCounter(TextThing)<TData> {
  constructor(data: TData, initialCount = 0) {
    super(data);
    this._counter = initialCount;
  }

  // Overriding a getter defined in the mixin seems fine...
  override get count(): number {
    return this._counter + 1;
  }

  // Overriding a base class abstract function implemented in mixin seems fine...
  html(): string {
    return `<p><strong>${this.count}: </strong>${this.dataSource}</p>`;
  }

  // But base class abstract getter implemented in the mixin throws an error?
  //  > 'text' is defined as a property in class 'WithCounter<typeof TextThing>.(Anonymous class)
  //     & TextThing<TData>', but is overridden here in 'TextWithCounter<TData>' as an
  //     accessor.ts(2611)
  override get text(): string {
    return `[${this.count}]: ${this.dataSource}`;
  }
}
```

This project is currently using TypeScript v4.5.4, but could probably upgrade if it'd help? I can't quite tell if this is a bug/limitation or an issue with our code...